# How do you change dependencies at runtime in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Say I have the following controller:

```
var MyController = function(dataSource) {
    this.something = dataSource.getSomething();
}
```

But I want to inject a different implementation of `dataSource` depending on whether or not I'm online or offline (e.g. `LocalStorageDataSource` and `APIDataSource`).

What is the mechanism in Angular that would let me do that both on script  startup, and also when an offline/online event fires?

Basically I'm trying to achieve polymorphic dependency injection at runtime in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from TodoMVC Angular:

https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/angularjs/js/services/todoStorage.js

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for. Thanks!